# Some label illegal when generate classes from JSON

Tags: c#, json

I send a GET request but in the response there are several "$" which are illegal characters in visual studio 2017.

For example, a part of the response is :

```
    "id": {
            "$t": "https://api.douban.com/collection/1226526807"
        },
    "db:status": {
            "$t": "wish"
        }
```

and then in https://jsonutils.com/ i general a class, it would be like this:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Id
    {

        [DataMember(Name="$t")]
        public string $t { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class DbStatus
    {

        [DataMember(Name="$t")]
        public string $t { get; set; }
    }
```

in VS2017 I got such errors:

[image]

translated into Eng is that in Class/struct/interface $ is invalid

And how to fix this? Thx~~

Comment: `public string $t` is invalid, you might want to consider something like an valid identifier name: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not put `$` in a  variable name.
Using [`NewtonSoft JSON`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) library , you can do something  like this:

```
[JsonProperty("$t")]
public string ApiUrl {get; set;}
```

If you can't use it, your only hope is to change the response if you have control over it or `jsonStr.Replace('$','')`